# Entity Framework not respecting Command Timeout

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I ran into an issue with my entity framework based api where 3rd party developers were mistakenly sending queries that were way too large and caused the system to drop performance. I've informed them to stop the practice but I would like to limit queries to 1 minute and then just cut them off.

It sounds like I should be able to just set the command timeout in the constructor (shown below). When I test it out with a long query it performs the query exactly as it was before (3+ minutes), it doesn't seem to be respecting the command timeout at all.

Did I do something wrong? Is this not how the command timeout is expected to work? It is async, does the command timeout not work with async? Any solutions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class CustomContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomContext(string connectionName)
        : base(connectionName)
    {
        var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = 60;
    }

    public CustomContext(EntityConnection connection)
        : base(connection, contextOwnsConnection: false)
    {
        var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = 60;
    }
}
```

Comment: For one, you can use `this.Database.CommandTimeout`. In my experience (Sql Server) it just works. Are you sure it's the SQL command that takes a long time? It could also be in-memory processing afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

**Entity Framework 6:**

```
this.context.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
```

**Entity Framework 5:**

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this.context).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;
```

**Entity Framework 4 and below:**

```
this.context.CommandTimeout = 180;
```